# Intellisense not working in VS2010 on Existing Websites

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have the strangest error in VS 2010, that I have been Googling for 2 days and nothing fixes it. The site was built in 2005. But my co-workers can open it in 2010 and get intellisense.

I can't get it for anything in App_Code. Which would make sense if opened as "Web Application". But its created and opened as "website"

So here is what works: 
(1) Open "new Website" --> Go to existing site directory --> Get prompt that it exists --> Select "open existing website" --> I get intellisense.

(2) Close VS, use solution file from above, no intellisense.

(3) Close VS, Open same site as "Open Website" --> No intellisense.

Reason i even found this work around, if just trial and error. But I don't want to create a new project every single time I open a website. It creates a bunch of temp files under C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET every time. Plus site is huge, and it takes forever to load.

Any ideas why my settings won't stick. I tried to take setting from a Virtual Machine where it works when opening existing website. No luck.

Tried to reset settings. No luck.

Reinstalled VS.

Any ideas? Cause I'm stomped.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this is you or not, but this happened at my company.

If ALL the following statements are true:

1. Using SQL Management Studio 2008 R2
2. Connecting to a SQL 2008 or higher database server
3. Have Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 installed
4. Intellisense in SQL Management Studio is not working

Management Studio uses the Visual Studio editor and VS2010 SP1 broke Management Studio’s Intellisense feature

You can fix the problem by installing the cumulative update.  Please install this only if Intellisense is broken in Management Studio.

---

Noticed you're looking for the .ncb files...  Starting with Visual Studio 2010, it no longer uses the .ncb system. Instead, it creates a file with a .sdf extension.

if you'd rather let Visual Studio handle it then you can go Tools / Options / Text Editor / C/C++ / Advanced / Browsing/Navigation / Recreate Database : True, then restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Still having problems. But those were good suggestions. I tried both. Thanks for feedback.